# On keyup get each input values to php script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get each input value on keyup with comma separated. My code is working fine with onclick event but not with on keyup.

```
<input type="text" class="date" name="date[]" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" />
```

This is part of my js function showhint where i'm defining the input value.

```
var DoB = [];
$(".date").each(function(){
     DoB.push($(this).val());
});
var newDob = DoB.slice(0,-1);

xmlhttp.open("GET","validation.php?q="+newDob+",true);
```

Can anyone help me with this what is my mistake here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the issue is the `keyup`? It seems to me the `DoB.slice(0, -1)` is causing your code not to work.

I replaced it with a `DoB.join(',');` to create the comma separated string.

```js
function showHint(someValue) {

var DoB = [];
$(".date").each(function(){
     //console.log($(this).val());
     DoB.push($(this).val());
});
//var newDob = DoB.slice(0, -1);
var newDob = DoB.join(',');
document.getElementById("URL").value = "validation.php?q="+newDob;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="date" name="date[]" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" />
<input type="text" class="date" name="date[]" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" />

<br>URL : <input type="text" size="50" id="URL"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting the code. i tried with this but i'm getting this error.

myfile.js:352 Uncaught ReferenceError: newDob is not defined
    at showHint (myfile.js:352)
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup (VM3224 :618)
showHint    @   myfile.js:352
onkeyup @   VM3224 :618

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$( ".date" ).keyup(function() {
   DoB.push($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, you don't have to keep array DoB. as you have only one dob element. and you can directly get value of input.

following code will work for you

```
function showHint(){
    var DoB = $(".date").val();
    console.log(DoB);
    xmlhttp.open("GET","validation.php?q="+DoB +",true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this happen to me before, when I used the onkeyup event in the script itself it works fine for me.

Here's an example:

```js
document.getElementById("fname").onkeyup = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fname");
    x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Press a key inside the text field and release it to set the text to uppercase.</p>

Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname">
</body>
</html>
```